# Modify CSS of main content when a side panel slides in

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the right panel is expanded, I want to fade out the content of the page and add css position to the background to make it slide to the left, is it possible? I can't modify the content when the panel is expanded because it doesn't receive an active class. Tried an "add class" in the JS for the content but didn't work.

https://codepen.io/darcyvoutt/pen/rhtfk

```
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="reveal-left">Left Panel</a>
    <a href="#" class="reveal-right">Right Panel</a>
</div>

<div class="panel-left">
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <div class="bottom">
      Some content here.
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce bibendum, orci ut sagittis tristique, diam nisi dapibus elit, quis volutpat tortor dui interdum lacus. Proin commodo nibh arcu, sed pellentesque nunc facilisis in. Sed id dui sed dui adipiscing interdum at id lectus. Nullam auctor, sem tincidunt aliquam posuere, tellus neque tempus est, sed pulvinar mi quam et erat. Suspendisse venenatis scelerisque ultrices. Cras congue arcu quam, vitae hendrerit est aliquet ut. Pellentesque et iaculis diam, eu adipiscing mauris. Vivamus porta, nisi sed tempor ullamcorper, massa enim tincidunt metus, ut rutrum nulla tellus vitae leo. In ac elementum elit. Ut ultricies eros luctus massa feugiat, vel mattis felis sollicitudin. Proin tellus arcu, consequat vitae est quis, tempus tempus sapien.
</p><p>
Phasellus sed velit quis dolor tristique interdum. Nullam interdum, metus ultricies tincidunt pharetra, leo purus porttitor velit, non tincidunt mauris nibh quis ipsum. Donec eget elit tristique, porttitor tortor id, vestibulum nulla. Nam in libero nec erat pretium pharetra ut ut neque. Nunc tincidunt, augue interdum vulputate laoreet, magna eros mollis nunc, cursus laoreet nulla lorem ut nibh. Donec arcu nunc, viverra quis pellentesque a, posuere a mauris. Vestibulum sollicitudin justo in sapien elementum adipiscing. Nulla sit amet diam vel massa tristique aliquam eu sit amet metus. Cras ac nunc enim. Sed at velit sed mauris lobortis accumsan id ac nisi. Duis ut vestibulum quam. Sed quis lacinia est.
</p><p>
Praesent quam lorem, faucibus sit amet risus et, bibendum vestibulum nunc. Integer vestibulum nunc a magna ti</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-right">
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <p>Right Panel</p> 
    <div class="bottom">
      Some content here.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h2>Side Panels Test</h2>
  <p>This is a prototype test to create two side panels that are controlled by CSS in terms of their animation. Click either the "Left Panel" or "Right Panel" buttons to reveal the panel. Then click on the <code>✖</code> close or use the keyboard shortcuts as seen below:</p>
    <ul>
      <li><code>ESC</code> - Close all windows</li>
      <li><code>L</code> - Open Right panel</li>
      <li><code>R</code> - Open Left panel</li>
    </ul>      
</div>
```

CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  background: #84D5C5;
  line-height: 1.5em;  
  font-size: 15px;
}

code {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background: #efefef;
  border-radius: 3px;  
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

h1, h2, h3 { margin-bottom: 0.5em; }

ul { margin: 30px 40px; }

li { margin: 5px 0; }
////////////////////////
// Mixins 
////////////////////////

.transition(@property) {
  -webkit-transition: @property;
  transition: @property;
}

.boxStyle() {
  background: #ffffff; 
  padding: 50px;
}

.panels() {
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background: #eeeeee; 
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.panelClose() {  
  @size: 15px; 
  @margin: 5px;  
  line-height: @size;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center; 
  cursor: pointer;  
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  right: @margin;
  top: @margin; 
  height: @size;
  width: @size;
  content: "✖";  
}

////////////////////////
// Panels & Reveal 
////////////////////////

.panel { 
  @transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  padding: 20px;
  
  &-content {
    position: relative;
    background: #efefef;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
    
    .close { 
      .panelClose();

      &:before { .panelClose(); }
    }
  }
  
  &-left {
    .panels();     
    .transition(@transition);
    left: -100%;
    width: 45%;
    
    &.expanded { left: 50px; }
  }
  
  &-right {
    .panels();       
    .transition(@transition);     
    right: -100%;    
    width: 50%; 
    
    &.expanded { right: 0; }
  }
}

.reveal {
  &-left {
    float: left;
  }
  &-right {
    float: right;
  }  
}

////////////////////////
// Layout 
////////////////////////

.nav {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  
  button {
    padding: 4px 6px;
  }
  
  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #222;
  }
}

.content {
  .boxStyle();
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
}

.bottom {
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

JS

```
// Reveal & Close Panels
var revealPanel = function (buttonReveal, panel, buttonClose) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Reveal panel 
    $(buttonReveal).on('click', function() {
      $(panel).addClass('expanded');
    });
    
    // Close panel
    $(buttonClose).on('click', function() {
      $(panel).removeClass('expanded');
    });   
    
    // ESC to close Panel
    $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) { $(panel).removeClass('expanded'); }    
    });
  }); 
}

revealPanel('.reveal-right','.panel-right', '.close');
revealPanel('.reveal-left','.panel-left', '.close');

// Reveal Panel with Shortcuts
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 76) { $('.panel-left').addClass('expanded'); }
    if (e.keyCode == 82) { $('.panel-right').addClass('expanded'); }
  });
});
```

Comment: When you say you want to "*fade out the content of the page*", I presume you mean you want to reduce the opacity of the main content? And what do you mean by "*add css position to the background*"?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. First of all sorry for my bad english. What I mean is, when i click for example on Right Panel, the right panel show up, and what I want is that the content move to the left and the background changing color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a class on the expand/close of the right panel that will:

- fade the main content by changing  the `opacity` CSS from 1 to 0.3 (for example)
- move it to the right using the `right` from 0 to 50% (to match your right panel)

The `transition` rule in the `.content` CSS will animate the change.

(You only mention the right panel in your question, but it can be adapted for the left panel also).

**See the working snippet:**

```js
// Reveal & Close Panels
var revealPanel = function (buttonReveal, panel, buttonClose) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Reveal panel 
    $(buttonReveal).on('click', function() {
      $(panel).addClass('expanded');
      $(".content").addClass('hidefor-'+panel.substr(1));
    });
    
    // Close panel
    $(buttonClose).on('click', function() {
      $(panel).removeClass('expanded');
      $(".content").removeClass('hidefor-panel-right');
    });   
    
    // ESC to close Panel
    $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
          $(panel).removeClass('expanded'); 
          $(".content").removeClass('hidefor-panel-right');
      }    
    });
  }); 
}

revealPanel('.reveal-right','.panel-right', '.close');
revealPanel('.reveal-left','.panel-left', '.close');

// Reveal Panel with Shortcuts
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 76) { 
    console.log(e.keyCode);
        $('.panel-left').addClass('expanded'); 
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 82) { 
        $('.panel-right').addClass('expanded'); 
        $(".content").addClass('hidefor-panel-right');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;  
  opacity:1;
  right:0;
}
.content.hidefor-panel-right { 
    opacity:0.3;
    right: 50%;
}


*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  background: #84d5c5;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 15px;
}
code {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background: #efefef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
ul {
  margin: 30px 40px;
}
li {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.panel {
  padding: 20px;
}
.panel-content {
  position: relative;
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 30px 50px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.panel-content .close {
  line-height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  content: "✖";
}
.panel-content .close:before {
  line-height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  content: "✖";
}
.panel-left {
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #eeeeee;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  left: -100%;
  width: 45%;
}

.panel-left.expanded {
  left: 0;
}
.panel-right {
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #eeeeee;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  right: -100%;
  width: 50%;
}
.panel-right.expanded {
  right: 0;
}
.reveal-left {
  float: left;
}
.reveal-right {
  float: right;
}
.nav {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10px;
  width: 90%;
}
.nav button {
  padding: 4px 6px;
}
.nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #222;
}

.bottom {
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="reveal-left">Left Panel</a>
    <a href="#" class="reveal-right">Right Panel</a>
</div>

<div class="panel-left">
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <div class="bottom">
      Some content here.
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce bibendum, orci ut sagittis tristique, diam nisi dapibus elit, quis volutpat tortor dui interdum lacus. Proin commodo nibh arcu, sed pellentesque nunc facilisis in. Sed id dui sed dui adipiscing interdum at id lectus. Nullam auctor, sem tincidunt aliquam posuere, tellus neque tempus est, sed pulvinar mi quam et erat. Suspendisse venenatis scelerisque ultrices. Cras congue arcu quam, vitae hendrerit est aliquet ut. Pellentesque et iaculis diam, eu adipiscing mauris. Vivamus porta, nisi sed tempor ullamcorper, massa enim tincidunt metus, ut rutrum nulla tellus vitae leo. In ac elementum elit. Ut ultricies eros luctus massa feugiat, vel mattis felis sollicitudin. Proin tellus arcu, consequat vitae est quis, tempus tempus sapien.
</p><p>
Phasellus sed velit quis dolor tristique interdum. Nullam interdum, metus ultricies tincidunt pharetra, leo purus porttitor velit, non tincidunt mauris nibh quis ipsum. Donec eget elit tristique, porttitor tortor id, vestibulum nulla. Nam in libero nec erat pretium pharetra ut ut neque. Nunc tincidunt, augue interdum vulputate laoreet, magna eros mollis nunc, cursus laoreet nulla lorem ut nibh. Donec arcu nunc, viverra quis pellentesque a, posuere a mauris. Vestibulum sollicitudin justo in sapien elementum adipiscing. Nulla sit amet diam vel massa tristique aliquam eu sit amet metus. Cras ac nunc enim. Sed at velit sed mauris lobortis accumsan id ac nisi. Duis ut vestibulum quam. Sed quis lacinia est.
</p><p>
Praesent quam lorem, faucibus sit amet risus et, bibendum vestibulum nunc. Integer vestibulum nunc a magna ti</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-right">
  <div class="panel-content">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <p>Right Panel</p> 
    <div class="bottom">
      Some content here.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h2>Side Panels Test</h2>
  <p>This is a prototype test to create two side panels that are controlled by CSS in terms of their animation. Click either the "Left Panel" or "Right Panel" buttons to reveal the panel. Then click on the <code>✖</code> close or use the keyboard shortcuts as seen below:</p>
    <ul>
      <li><code>ESC</code> - Close all windows</li>
      <li><code>L</code> - Open Right panel</li>
      <li><code>R</code> - Open Left panel</li>
    </ul>      
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I had in mind :D

Comment: Glad to help! The code is written in a way that you can do the same for the left panel by adding a similar `.content.hidefor.panel-left` class with the required CSS, so you should be able to adapt it to your needs :)

Comment: Sorry, just curious. Why the shorcut which is "R" doesn't work anymore ? Edit : It does work, but the effect of the content don't.

Comment: @SeitoKimbo Sorry, I had changed the name of my class and forgot to update it everywhere. The JS using class name `faded` just needs to be changed - I've updated the answer to fix this, check the code in the `$(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {` section, that has the changes (`$(".content").addClass` for the 2 keyCode comparisons)

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not working :/. I mean the panel show up, but the effects on the content don't apply.

Comment: @SeitoKimbo Sorry!! It was working, but I changed it somehow before saving.  Answer is updated, just a single change - in `if (e.keyCode == 82) ` change `$(".content").addClass('content.hidefor-panel-right');` to `$(".content").addClass('hidefor-panel-right');` I've checked *after* saving this time and its still working!

Comment: Thank you so so much man !! I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @SeitoKimbo *Wo*man, not man :) No problem, sorry again for the errors!

Comment: Wohow my bad :p